# Mostrar clave y valor de un diccionario en reportlab python

Tags: python, pdf, djangorestframework, reportlab

Estoy usando reportlab para generar pdf. Tengo esta función en django rest framework, en la cual tengo un diccionario llamado datos, estoy haciendo un for para reccorrer esa data y mostrar su clave y valor en el pdf, para ello hago esto:

```
@api_view()
def hello_world(request):
  
   todos =
[
   {
      primer_apellido : Castro,
      segundo_apellido : Mendieta,
      primer_nombre : José,
      segundo_nombre : Raúl,
      genero : masculino,
      lugar_de_nacimiento : Cuenca - Azuay,
      fecha_de_nacimiento : 1967-10-20,
      provincia : Loja,
      canton : Cuenca,
      ciudad : Loja,
      parroquia : El Vecino,
      direccion : Turunuma Alto. Urb. Elite. Casa A1.,
      telefono_institucion : 13213213,
      email_principal : jrcastro@utpl.edu.ec
   }
]
 
    buffer = io.BytesIO()

    # Create the PDF object, using the buffer as its "file."
    p = canvas.Canvas(buffer)

    # # Draw things on the PDF. Here's where the PDF generation happens.
    # # See the ReportLab documentation for the full list of functionality.

    from reportlab.lib import colors 
    from reportlab.lib.units import inch 
    y = x = 0
    dy = inch*3/4.0
    dx = inch*5.5/5
    w = h = dy/2
    rdx = (dx-w)/2    
    rdy = h/5.0
    texty = h+2*rdy    
    for todo in todos:
        p.drawString(x+dx/2, y+texty, todo, todos[todo])        
        x = x+dx    
        y = y + dy
        x = 0
    
    # Close the PDF object cleanly, and we're done.
    p.showPage()
    p.save()

    # FileResponse sets the Content-Disposition header so that browsers
    # present the option to save the file.
    buffer.seek(0)

    return FileResponse(buffer, as_attachment=True, filename='hello.pdf')
```

Uso la funcion `drawString` de reportlab, pero solo me deja hacer esto `p.drawString(x+dx/2, y+texty, todo)` con lo que puedo mostrar solo la clave y no la clave y el valor. Como puedo hacer para que se muestre la clave y el valor o si existe algún otra función de reportlab para poder hacerlo. Espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias de antemano

Comment: para acceder al valor de un diccionario se hace con su clave `dic[key]`, no se nada de reportlab pero la clave es la variable `todo` ya accedes con `todos[todo]`, pues eso es la sintaxis de los diccionarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo pude solucionar de esta forma:

```
p.drawString(x1, y1-10, f"{k}: {v}")
```

Ya que la función `drawString` solo permite tener tres parámetros.

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente concatena strings en la llamada a `drawString`, por ejemplo:

```
p.drawString(x+dx/2, y+texty, todo + ' = ' + str(todos[todo]))
```